# Check if a string equals '*'

Tags: ruby, calculator

I am attempting to make a console based calculator to practice some Ruby, I am using the 'case' statement to check the consoles arguments then use Ruby's arithmetic to interpret and return the result.

The issue I am having is that I cannot get Ruby to execute the line associated with the Multiplication. It simply goes to the 'else' block and executes my help method. I have all other methods except the Exponent I assume Ruby is treating the STAR characters as 'Everything' (I am not sure how to word that)

```
case @args[1]
when '+'
  puts "#{@args[0].to_i + @args[2].to_i}"
when '-'
  puts "#{@args[0].to_i - @args[2].to_i}"
when '*'
  puts "#{@args[0].to_i * @args[2].to_i}"
when '/'
  puts "#{@args[0].to_i / @args[2].to_i}"
when '%'
  puts "#{@args[0].to_i % @args[2].to_i}"
when '**'
  puts "#{@args[0].to_i**@args[2].to_i}"
else
  help
end
```

I know it looks dodgy, bare in mind I plan on fixing it up once I have everything working.

I am fairly new to Ruby so I am not 100% sure on what I need to do to have Ruby treat these as simple stars and not Regular Expressions...

I assure you this is not homework, I am simply trying to learn some Ruby as I have also recently started learning Rails.

Comment: Let me guess: You're running this from a shell with something like `ruby yourscript.rb 2 * 2`? Then your shell will likely treat the `*` as a [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) and expand it before it even reaches your script.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying yes, exactly. "./clk 5 * 8" I will go do some research on how to escape that in zsh. Thanks hammer.

EDIT: I escaped with \* at my shell. Consider this question RESOLVED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try escaping the asterisk by writing '\*'?

Comment: Ah I see, I will test that now. EDIT: That didn't work, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. hammar was spot on.

Answer (score 0):

There's something else going on. This irb session confirms that strings in case statements work the way you expect:

```
str = '*'
=> "*"
>> case str
>> when '*' then "foo"
>> end
=> "foo"
```

Double check that `@args[1]` actually is what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks Rein, but it was actually my shell messing with the * symbol as mentioned by 'hammer' in the commends section of my question, thank you though.

Comment: And don't forget, that what you actually want to do is not a `case` statement, but `calculator.send @args[1], @args[0], @args[2]`, and having `calculator` object methods such as `#+` and `#*` defined, all that in a statement catching `NoMethodError`.